# When will my on-hold question be reopened and how do I know its current status?

Tags: support, questions, reopen-closed, on-hold

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38147372/3001761) and it was placed **on hold**. I read that questions on hold will be closed after 5 days if there is no improvement. I have edited my question, but it's still on-hold.

How long does it take to be reviewed? Has it been seen by the reviewers? How can I check its current status?

Comment: It's still pending [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12895158)...

Comment: Whats wrong in my question.? Why give minus vote instead of giving clear solution.?

Comment: @Twisty.. You have said it's in pending review, but their is no notification for that, even i did 3 edits.. My quesion [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147372/how-to-rotate-image-without-starting-always-from-zeroth-degree-when-leaving-rota)

Comment: I would like to ask those who gave negative votes for this question., is there any other location or link my question asked before or solution found..?

Comment: It didn't pass review. Ditch the *"thanks"* noise and give a MCVE *in the question itself*, using Stack Snippets not an off-site fiddle.

Comment: @ArunValaven those negative votes here to do not impact your reputation as you hopefully have noticed.  Because they don't impact your rep, votes tend to used more freely, and sometimes used to express agreement/disagreement.  I don't know why the individual users voted, but one possible reason is they don't think your question should be reopened.  You can read more in [What's Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @psubsee2003..... ok

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147372/how-to-rotate-image-without-starting-always-from-zeroth-degree-when-leaving-rota) was originally closed as "Too broad". While you did edit it, there are still several problems with your post:

- Your code is only on JSFiddle, and not in the question itself.
- You lack an example image and example expected behavior.
- There is lots of noise in your question (e.G "Thanks in advance" or "Please help me soon")

As it stands, I don't think this question should be reopened. As to your question how the reopen process works, your question was first reviewed in the Reopen Review Queue about an hour ago. The review [was completed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12895158) with the Outcome of 3x "Leave Closed" 5 minutes ago, which means that the community still considers your question as not worthy to be reopened.

Comment: Nitpicking, but correct capitalization of all "I" would also be nice.

Comment: @Magisch.. You have pointed-out a valid points where i gone wrong. Then, just now i came to know that a question review status can able to view. Where this link(http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/questioncode) is available in stackoverflow..?

Comment: I am eager to know more and more about stackoverflow, but some negative voters make degrade my willingness...

Comment: Another thing I'd add is the phrase, "Don't prescribe me to rotate using Jquery UI rotatable." is a problem as well.  Why can't you use it, or why don't you want to use it?  You need to provide some context for these vague demands, as it will help users understand your problem.

Comment: @psubsee2003.. Ok..

Comment: @ArunValaven: as a new user, you probably should have started by reading the introductory [tour]. See the [help] for further tips on how to ask better questions.

Comment: @ArunValaven To see the votes of your post, you can can go to [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38147372/timeline) of your post. To get there you can use this link: `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/[id_of_post_here]/timeline`. The ID of the post can be found in the url. :) (I'm not sure if the preview only occurs after it is completed, or also when it is still in progress though.)